# Django HttpResponseRedirect redirects me wrong

Tags: python, django, django-views, httpresponse, django-urls

I want to redirect a link, for example

*mydomain.com/my_app/0* -------> redirect to : *mydomain.com/my_app/finance*

but it redirects to
*mydomain.com/my_app/0/finance*

could you help me to fix this?

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse , HttpResponseNotFound , Http404 , HttpResponseRedirect 
articles = {
    'finance' : 'finance page',
    'sports' : 'sports page'
}
def news_view (request,topic):
    return HttpResponse(articles[topic])

def num_page_view(request,num_page):
    topics_list = list(articles.keys())
    topic = topics_list[num_page]
    return HttpResponseRedirect(topic)
```

urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:num_page>/',views.num_page_view),
    path('<str:topic>/',views.news_view)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, use the `redirect` function instead of `HttpResponseRedirect`

To do this, first give a name to each of the paths

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:num_page>/', views.num_page_view, name='num_page_view'),
    path('<str:topic>/', views.news_view, name='news_view'),
]
```

Finally, use the `redirect` function

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def num_page_view(request, num_page):
    topics_list = list(articles.keys())
    topic = topics_list[num_page]
    return redirect('news_view', topic=topic)
```

Comment: thanks but i want to do it in that way